# Bar plot with median +/- median absolute deviation in scientific publication

Tags: median, barplot, mad

I know bar plots usually represents mean +/- sem, but if the data is non-normal, is it ok to bar plot median +/- mad?

I don't like box plots.

Suggestison?

Comment: SEM represents the expected error in your sample mean value versus the population mean; it depends on the number of observations. The MAD, like the standard deviation, represents the variation of the population about the median/mean, independent of the number of observations. Which type of information do you wish to display? Also, you will find that many professional statisticians profoundly dislike bar plots, despite their common use. See, e.g., <http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/StatGraphCourse/graphscourse.pdf> for why box plots and other displays may be preferable.

Comment: Yes, Im aware that SEM is not SD/MAD. The reason I ask is because scientific journals usually use mean +/- SEM for bar  plots, disregarding if the data is normal. Optimally they should use mean +/- SD in bar plots, which they don't. I now ask if I can use median +/- MAD in a bar plot, or will they complain and make me use mean +/- SEM. Any experience?

Comment: Depends on the journal. Optimally, they probably shouldn't use bar plots at all (or at most sparingly). I'd suggest using what you think is most appropriate to your data and the point you're trying to make, and deal with the editors' and reviewers' comments later (if any). And please re-think your objection to boxplots, which can be extremely useful to the reader who wants to look at your results in more detail.

Comment: Yes, I actually have. Im now looking for a way to box plot, but showing, and labelling, individual values.

Comment: In R, the `points` or `stripchart` function adds data points to the boxplot, and the `text` function can label them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992508/labeling-the-scatterplot-point-in-boxplot-and-the-summary-of-the-boxplot-in-the for the general approach. In practice, unless you have a lot of labeling, labeling points by hand might be faster than learning the syntax for automatic labeling. For this type of coding question, as opposed to a statistical question, http://stackoverflow.com should give you quicker and maybe better answers.

Comment: I didn't need to ask, I figured it out. I now have a very nice plot Im really happy with. I ended up using boxplot() + stripchart() + interaction.plot(). Now, Im writing a function to add indications of significant differences between comparisons.